# How to properly style React Rich Text Editor (react-rte)

Tags: reactjs, rte

I want to style react-rte using a CSS file, but was unable to do so.

The RichTextEditor always injects inline styles into bottom of HEAD section, which overriden my class styling.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far...

Answer (score 5):

Ass seen in [EditorDemo.js](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/blob/master/src/EditorDemo.js) you can define classes for toolbar and editor

```
<RichTextEditor
  toolbarClassName="demo-toolbar"
  editorClassName="demo-editor"
/>
```